# How to bson.UnmarshalExtJSON to parse Time string into ISODate

Tags: go, mongo-go

I have raw json:

```
{
    "@timestamp":"2019-05-05T19:54:00.455+08:00"
}
```

and I have defined struct:

```
type A struct {
    Timestamp string bson:"@timestamp"
}
```

How to realize it with `bson.UnmarshalExtJSON`?